# How to translate this line of code from C++ to Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I need to translate this line from C++ to Objective-C
but I don't really understand this line

```
IntVar* MakeIntVar(int64 vmin, int64 vmax, const std::string& name);
```

This seems to be for me a function without a return value?

IntVar is by the way a class

```
class IntVar;
```

Comment: But `IntVar*` is the return value. Please learn C++ properly and don't translate between languages, that never ends in good code, even if the original was.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer - now I understand a little more -  normally I don´t need C++, but in my case I need a bridging header for this

Comment: @Dschella _"... without a return value?"_ The return value clearly is `IntVar*`???

Comment: @Dschella Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Thank you - It seems that I need to learn to understand Stack Overflow better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is an extension of C. You should be used to calling Objective-C methods and C functions.

For methods you define them in an `@interface`, usually written in a `.h` file, and implement them in a `@class`, written in a `.m` file.

You may not write many C functions but you use them: e.g. `NSLog()`, `sin()`, *et al*. C functions are standalone, not part of a class as in C, but you usually have a definition (or *prototype*) in a `.h` and the implementation in a `.c`.

If the C part above is unfamiliar then write a call to `NSLog` (or `sin` etc.) in your Objective-C code and then lookup its definition (in Xcode select `NSLog`, right/control click and select "Jump to Definition"). You will see a line rather similar to the one in your question.

What you have is the definition of a function (`MakeIntVar`) which takes three arguments and returns a value. The thirds argument of the function has a C++ type and is a C++ reference argument (the `&` bit), you'll need to understand C++ to know how to call this function.

It is unclear from your question/comments whether you are translating C++ into Objective-C or trying to call C++ from Objective-C. If the latter you may need to write some bridging code in *Objective-C++* (written in a `.mm` file). You will need to study how to write Objective-C++ and call it from Objective-C etc.

HTH